# How to call dynamic web service from ActiveX Control created using C#.net?

Tags: web-services, url, dynamic, activex, endpoint

I have an activex control which call a web service.This web service can be hosted anywhere hence don't know its url.
But we can send the web service url into activex control from the web page in which we have used activex control.
I want to dynamically set the url in activex control so that it will replace the one that is used during creation of installer.

I have already tried following code in usercontrol of activex control

```
ServiceReference1.abcServiceSoapClient c = new ServiceReference1.abcServiceSoapClient("abcServiceSoap");
c.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("WebServiceURL");
```

but give following exception

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.abcServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

In case of WinForm or WebForm, this exception is handle by appending the content of 'app.config' of class library into 'App.config' in winform and 'Web.config' in webform.

But don't know what to do in case of activex control library as it is embedded in web form.

So, please suggest how can a dynamic web service URL be set in activex control so that the control will call the web service send by web page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** it by using **Web Reference** instead of **Service Reference**.

Code snippet shown below

```
 WebReference1.abcWebService client = new WebReference1.abcWebService();
 client.Url = WebServiceURL;
```